# How can i display attribute on Detail tab?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to display my custom attribute on "Detail" Tab.
(now it display on "More information" tab)

Thanks !

Comment: Create a new tab Give a name detail than call description/Short description along with your attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml` in your custom theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

Here you need to check if `$_code == "description"` and show product custom attribute like

```
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_className ?>">
    ....
    ....
    <?php
        if($_code == "description") {
            echo $_product->getCustomAttribute(); // Get product custom attribute
        }
    ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this below code in your `catalog_product_view.xml` file.

> app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main product-shop col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.measurements" template="product/view/customattribute.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMeasurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="measurements"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, create `customattribute.phtml` for your custom attribute display in details tab

> app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/customattribute.phtml

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue) { ?>
    <div class="product attibute <?php echo $_className?>">
    <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>>
        <?php echo $_attributeValue;
        if($_code == "description") {
            echo $_product->getCustomAttribute();
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```